# Jenkins /buildWithParameters returns HTML

Tags: rest, jenkins

When calling Jenkins /buildWithParameters endpoint an HTML is returned instead of a Json. Also, there is a redirection (302) to the job page. There is also no way to obtain the created build number.

The Location header of the redirection is wrong, also the status which should be 201 instead of 302.

Comment: Please supply more information. With this little information there is only guesswork possible. Exact REST call (e. g. `curl` arguments if used). Response HTML and response headers. Have you verified that the root URL of your Jenkins is correct and it has not actually moved to another location?

Comment: If I execute a curl like this: `curl -v -k -i -X POST 'https://jenkins/job/cicd/job/deployment/buildWithParameters' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic xxxxx' ` I receive back a 302 with the Location header to the job `https://jenkins/job/cicd/job/deployment/'. If the '--location' option is added, the redirect is followed and an HTML is returned